# Are you able to use your insurance policy when you're involved in an innocent vehicle purchase situation?

Tags: fraud, insurance, vehicle

I purchased a vehicle for $70,000 with what could be a false title. Unfortunately the California DMV was able to register the vehicle, so they too did not know this title or name on the title was possibly fake. I received my registration and eventually vehicle title in the mail. The vehicle was also fully insured and remained this way for aproximately 3-4 months, until the vehicle was finally reported “stolen”. The vehicle was taken by law enforcement for further investigation of the parties involved in the sale. At this point if the vehicle is returned to the “rightful” owner, am I able to file a claim through my insurance for full compensation?

Comment: This surely depends on what type of insurance you have.

Comment: Hello Hector, and welcome to law.SE! Unfortunately, your question is missing important detail. Please edit it to explain what type of insurance you have (liability, comprehensive coverage etc.) you have, and the jurisdiction you are in.

Comment: Just as a note: What you need (would have needed ) is probably "title insurance" for the car purchase.

Comment: I’m in the Monterey County (California) and I currently still have full coverage on the vehicle through Allstate Insurance even tough the vehicle is no longer in my possession and is still with law enforcement for further investigation. As to further information to the transaction, the vehicle was previously a luxury rental and an organized crime of individuals were the ones who sold me the car. The “previous owner” and independent vehicle renter did not report the car stolen until 3-4 months after the steal and sold it to me. This is why I was able to register and insured the vehicle.

Comment: @Hector, please add details to the question, not in a comment

Comment: The seller of the vehicle might be liable for fraud - they got money for a good they didn't deliver.

Answer (score 3):

### No

Auto insurance covers loss or damage to the vehicle - the vehicle is neither lost nor damaged.

The risk you describe is called title insurance and is normally bought for real estate.